# WooCommerce cart hook 'woocommerce_cart_contents' displaying content in the wrong position

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add content below the cart items and above the 'Apply Coupon' and 'Update Cart' buttons.

I am using the action hook `woocommerce_cart_contents`.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_cart_contents', 'add_content');
function add_content(){
    echo 'The content';
}
```

The echoed text is being displayed above the cart table.

[image]

I have tested this on two different websites and found the same issue. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the correct [hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart.php#L136), but since it concerns table rows,  wrap it in [`<table>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) tags

```php
function add_content(){
    echo '<tr><td>The content</td></tr>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_contents', 'add_content');
```